# Image resize in Grails

Tags: java, grails, image-processing, frameworks

I am developing a Web Album using Grails and for image processing, I am using grails-image-tools plugin. I need a functionality to resize the images if the uploaded images size is too big (for eg: more than 600 * 840 ) . In this case I need to resize this image to 600 * 840). What is the most efficient way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Image as AWTImage 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage      
import javax.swing.ImageIcon 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO as IIO  
import java.awt.Graphics2D


static resize = { bytes, out, maxW, maxH -> 
    AWTImage ai = new ImageIcon(bytes).image 
    int width = ai.getWidth( null ) 
    int height = ai.getHeight( null )

    def limits = 300..2000 
    assert limits.contains( width ) && limits.contains( height ) : 'Picture is either too small or too big!'

    float aspectRatio = width / height float requiredAspectRatio = maxW / maxH

    int dstW = 0 
    int dstH = 0 
    if (requiredAspectRatio < aspectRatio) { 
        dstW = maxW dstH = Math.round( maxW / aspectRatio) 
    } else { 
        dstH = maxH dstW = Math.round(maxH * aspectRatio) 
    }

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(dstW, dstH,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)            
    Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics() g2d.drawImage(ai, 0, 0, dstW, dstH, null, null) 

    IIO.write( bi, 'JPEG', out )
}
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes old question, but the reason that happens is because the image isn't really rotated in the first place—it just has EXIF data that instructs photo viewers (like browsers) to display the image rotated. Some cameras (and especially phones) do this instead of actually rotating the image. Since the image isn't really rotated, and the Java APIs don't look at the EXIF rotation data, the image ends up appearing to be rotated, even though in reality it's not. Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/9re/1990019) of code which checks the EXIF data and rotates accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

In `BuildConfig.groovy` add a dependency to [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.1'     
}
```

Then resizing images becomes a one-liner:

```
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, 150);
```

Comment: Don will it maintain the quality of the image. As i am using grails imageTools plugin but the quality of image it creates is very poor

Comment: @Charsee I am very pleased with the image quality

Comment: I was trying to use scalr but  I am getting  "No such property: Scalr for class...." error. Do I have to import it? Or will I have to do something more to get it working

Comment: yes, you need to import the Scalr class. Add the following to the list of imports in the class where you do the resizing `import org.imgscalr.Scalr`

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageTool plugin.
https://grails.org/plugin/image-tools
P.S. Available only for grails v2.

Comment: Any idea if it is compatible with Grails 2? Is it needed to build myself from git or is the latest release 0.1 also working?